# Скачивание всего кода страницы с помощью curl в linux

Tags: linux, curl

Столкнулся с проблемой, при просмотре страницы подкаталога каталога в github через curl, отправляется не полный файл. Пытался добавлять user-agent и заголовки, которые отправляет сам браузер, но не помогло. Лечится это тем, что нужно зайти в этот подкаталог с браузера, а уже потом загружать с curl, но данный вариант мне не подходит. На скриншоте представлено различие между двумя файлами(слева - до посещения этого каталога в браузере, справа - после)[[image: ---]---](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At0dU.jpg)
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Через ссылку raw качаешь?

Comment: Поддерживаю @eri, неплохо было бы добавить те комманды, которые юзаешь.

Comment: *нужно зайти в этот подкаталог с браузера, а уже потом загружать с curl* - 'это что за мистическая связь между *curl* и браузером ?!!! Вы откуда, чего и как пытаетесь забрать?